# What is $5^{250} \bmod{26}$, step by step?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, integers

I have attempted to solve this equation $5^{250} \bmod 26$, and the result I get is 1. However, a calculator says that the answer should be 25. I have done out the question in Paint to demonstrate my logic. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hint: $25\equiv -1 \bmod 26$

Comment: What makes you think that $5^{41}\equiv5^6\pmod{26}$ or that $5^{10}\equiv1\pmod{26}$?

Comment: If the main point of your question is asking for helping to check your own solution (as opposed to asking for *any* solution of the given problem) you should add ([tag:solution-verification]) tag.

Comment: Why do you believe that $5^{41} \equiv 1 \mod 26$ and why do you believe $5^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 26$?... oh, bof asked the exact same thing. ... but why *do* you?  $\phi(26) = 12$ so $25^{12}\equiv 1 \mod 26$ I understand but... why $41$?  And why $10$.  ... anyhow.  $5^2 =25\equiv -1 \mod 26$ should be the hint you need as Mark Bennet points out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$5^{10} \equiv (5^2)^{5} \equiv (-1)^{5}\equiv -1 \equiv 25 \pmod{26}$$

Answer (score 6):

It's $$25^{125}\equiv(-1)^{125}=-1.$$